# NullPointerException from Eclipse Compiler

Tags: eclipse

I am receiving the following message from my Eclipse compiler, and my project fails to compile....

Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.missingTypeInMethod(ProblemReporter.java:5075)

I've tried updating Eclipse, restarting eclipse, closing and opening the project, refreshing, cleaning/rebuilding, etc.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you "update" eclipse or made a clean fresh install of 3.5.1? That latter process could help getting rid of the error message. Also reimporting the project into a new workspace could help too.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be the [bug 250297](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=250297), fixed in eclipse 3.4.2. Also fixed in the 3.5 (M4, November 2008, as mentioned in this [JDT release notes](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.core/notes/R35_buildnotes_jdt-core.html?view=co))

> The failure occurs on line (>>>):

```
public void missingTypeInMethod(MessageSend messageSend, MethodBinding method)
{
    List missingTypes = method.collectMissingTypes(null);
>>> TypeBinding missingType = (TypeBinding) missingTypes.get(0);
```

> It would indicate that though we identified a missing type (which we try to complain against), we fail to locate it inside the method signature...

---

So... if you are using an "older" version of eclipse (like 3.4, or 3.4.1), a good solution is to upgrade (that is, install another fresh version of eclipse, 3.4.2 or 3.5.1), while reusing your same workspace.
The error should then go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as late as Eclipse Luna (4.4). The only way I found to get rid of it was to upgrade to Eclipse Mars (4.5.0). I don't know if this is relevant to the issue, but I upgraded to java 8 shortly before the problem arose.
HTH.